# Javascript - Get Image height

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to display a bunch of images on a web page using AJAX. All of them have different dimensions, so I want to adjust their size before displaying them. Is there any way to do this in JavaScript?

Using PHP's `getimagesize()` for each image causes an unnecessary performance hit since there will be many images.

Comment: I don't believe AJAX is used to display images. Typically images are added by modifying the src property of an existing html image tag or by dynamically creating a new one (or a new Image object).

Answer (score 83):

I was searching a solution to get height and width of an image using JavaScript. I found many, but all those solutions only worked when the image was present in browser cache.

Finally I found a solution to get the image height and width even if the image does not exist in the browser cache:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var imgHeight;
  var imgWidth;

  function findHHandWW() {
    imgHeight = this.height;
    imgWidth = this.width;
    return true;
  }

  function showImage(imgPath) {
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.name = imgPath;
    myImage.onload = findHHandWW;
    myImage.src = imgPath;
  }
</script>
```

Thanks,

Binod Suman

http://binodsuman.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-get-height-and-widht-of-image.html

Comment: I think the line `myImage.onload = findHHandWW;` should read `myImage.onload = findHHandWW();`. Editor won't let me add: not enough characters!

Comment: No, `myImage.onLoad = findHHandWW;` is right, it's passing the reference to the function here, not calling it and assigning the result.

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
var curHeight;
var curWidth;

function getImgSize(imgSrc)
{
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.src = imgSrc;
curHeight = newImg.height;
curWidth = newImg.width;

}
```

Comment: This solution has all the right parts, but doesn't give time for the image to load before reading the dimensions. An onload event for each image, and perhaps a closure, will make this work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `img.naturalWidth` and `img.naturalHeight` to get real dimension of image in pixels

Answer (score 2):

...but... wouldn't it be better to adjust the image size on the server side rather than transmitting the bytes to the browser and doing it there?

When I say adjust the image size, I don't mean set the height and width in the HTML image tag.   If you do that, you are still shipping a large number of bytes from server to client.  I mean, actually manipulate the image itself server side.

I have .NET C# code here that takes that approach, but there must be a php way to do it too:  http://ifdefined.com/www/gallery.html

Also, by doing it server side, that opens up the possibility of doing the adjustment just once and then saving the adjusted image, which would be very fast.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred solution for this would be to do the resizing server-side, so you are transmitting less unnecessary data.

If you have to do it client-side though, and need to keep the image ratio, you could use the below:

```
var image_from_ajax = new Image();
image_from_ajax.src = fetch_image_from_ajax(); // Downloaded via ajax call?

image_from_ajax = rescaleImage(image_from_ajax);

// Rescale the given image to a max of max_height and max_width
function rescaleImage(image_name)
{
    var max_height = 100;
    var max_width = 100;

    var height = image_name.height;
    var width = image_name.width;
    var ratio = height/width;

    // If height or width are too large, they need to be scaled down
    // Multiply height and width by the same value to keep ratio constant
    if(height > max_height)
    {
        ratio = max_height / height;
        height = height * ratio;
        width = width * ratio;
    }

    if(width > max_width)
    {
        ratio = max_width / width;
        height = height * ratio;
        width = width * ratio;
    }

    image_name.width = width;
    image_name.height = height;
    return image_name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jquery_get_width_height()
{
    var imgWidth = $("#img").width();
    var imgHeight = $("#img").height();
    alert("JQuery -- " + "imgWidth: " + imgWidth + " - imgHeight: " + imgHeight);
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function javascript_get_width_height()
{
    var img = document.getElementById('img');
    alert("JavaSript -- " + "imgWidth: " + img.width + " - imgHeight: " + img.height);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This will only work after images have already been displayed (added to page). Moreover the width and height determined this way shall reflect displayed size of an image (scaled by CSS, etc.), not its original size.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to adjust the images themselves, or just the way they display? If the former, you want something on the server side. If the latter, you just need to change image.height and image.width.

Answer (score 0):

Well...there are several ways to interpret this question.

The first way and the way I think you mean is to simply alter the display size so all images display the same size.  For this, I would actually use CSS and not JavaScript.  Simply create a class that has the appropriate width and height values set, and make all `<img>` tags use this class.

A second way is that you want to preserve the aspect ration of all the images, but scale the display size to a sane value.  There is a way to access this in JavaScript, but I'll need a bit to write up a quick code sample.

The third way, and I hope you don't mean this way, is to alter the actual size of the image.  This is something you'd have to do on the server side, as not only is JavaScript unable to create images, but it wouldn't make any sense, as the full sized image has already been sent.

Comment: Second is what I want to do and the images are not on my server but are getting loaded from outside, so I cannot pre-process them. I just have image urls.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that in Firefox 3 and Safari, resizing an image by just changing the height and width doesn't look too bad. In other browsers it can look very noisy because it's using nearest-neighbor resampling. Of course, you're paying to serve a larger image, but that might not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the image in a hidden `<img>` tag (`style = "display none"`), listen to the load event firing with jQuery, create a new `Image()` with JavaScript, set the source to the invisible image, and get the size like above.