# Detect The Height of an Image

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have several images(that have different sizes) on my project and to improve the layout of the page I've set this CSS for those images:

```
#Banners {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 350px;

    border: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
}

.float {
    float: left;
}
```

But some images are smaller than `350px` and the container they are in has the `min-height` set to `360px`, then it lefts a blank space on my page. So I want to get the actual `height` of the image(the `height` after passing the CSS code) and set the container `min-height` equal to the image `height` using jQuery. How to get the image `height` after being passed through the CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106828/javascript-get-image-height

Comment: i would just use .height() in jQuery :D

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do it, however I'm not sure why you need to set the min-height equal to the height of the image.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Banners").css("min-height", $("#img_id").outerHeight());
});
```

Comment: I think you'll need to get the image dimensions after the load event, not the ready event. Load: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ Ready: http://api.jquery.com/ready/