# query access img inside href tag

Tags: jquery

Hi I would like to get the height of the image inside the a href tag with a class of 'advance-link' of the following

```
<div id="gallery" class="content" style="display: block;">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
      <span class="image-wrapper current" style="opacity: 1;">
        <a class="advance-link" title="undefined" href="#2" rel="history">
          <img alt="undefined" src="images/experiments/large/experiments.jpg">
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect The Height of an Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483885/detect-the-height-of-an-image) -- for selecting the right element, I suggest you have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. We cannot have a question like this for every possible markup.

Comment: Fair enough but I did have a good look around and couldn't get it to work. The first post below has cracked it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the most simple, I'd suggest:

```
$('a.advance-link img').height();
```

This should be placed inside a `$(window).load()`, rather than `$(document).ready()`, since `load()` waits for images to load, while `ready()` simply waits for the DOM to be constructed and ready:

```
$(window).load(
    function(){
        var heightOfImage = $('a.advance-link img').height();
    });
```

References:

- [`$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()` difference](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/document-ready-and-window-onload-difference).
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).