# Javascript Image() return wrong Width and Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [Cross-Slide Jquery Plugin](https://github.com/tobia/CrossSlide) and I have a doubt.

When I try to load a image with dimensions 1176 x 1168, the `.width` propertie return 600 and the `.height` propertie return 595.

Why don't return the current dimensions of my image ?

**Plugin Code:**

```
 // first preload all the images, while getting their actual width and height
    (function (proceed) {
        var n_loaded = 0;
        function loop(i, img) {
            // for (i = 0; i < plan.length; i++) but with independent var i, img (for the closures)
            img.onload = function (e) {                
                n_loaded++;

                // Here are my doubt
                plan[i].width = img.width; // returning 600
                plan[i].height = img.height; // returning 595
                if (n_loaded == plan.length)
                    proceed();
            }
            img.src = plan[i].src;
            if (i + 1 < plan.length)
                loop(i + 1, new Image());
        }
        loop(0, new Image());

    })(function () {  // then proceed ...
```

Comment: What is the size of the `<img>` tag prior to loading anything?  I'm guessing 600 x 595.

Comment: Possibly of use: [Javascript - Get Image height](http://stackoverflow.com/a/952185/427192)

Comment: What about `.naturalWidth`?

Comment: That looks like it should work just fine. It creates a new image object, which would have the width and the height of the original image once loaded. Are you sure it's returning the wrong values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your code a bit (*mainly the `loop` function*) and try again, like this:

```
function loop(i, img) {
    img.src = plan[i].src;
    img.onload = function (e) {
        n_loaded++;
        plan[i].width = this.width; // Check the width now
        plan[i].height = this.height; // Check the height now
        if (n_loaded == plan.length) proceed();
    }
    if (i + 1 < plan.length) loop(i + 1, new Image());
}
```

[**SIMPLE DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CjUZ7/)

Answer (score 0):

did you tried like this?

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```