# Create JavaScript fill href based upon var

Tags: javascript, jquery, macros

I'm using a lovely Lightbox plugin that requires the following piece of code per image

```
<a href="images/portfolio/full/1.jpg"
   data-target="flare"      
   data-flare-plugin="shutter"
   data-flare-scale="fit"   
   data-flare-gallery="portfolio"
   data-flare-thumb="images/portfolio/thumbs/1.jpg"
   data-flare-bw="images/portfolio/bw/1.jpg"
   class="kleur multiple">    
       <img src="images/portfolio/thumbs/1.jpg" width="375px" height="250px"   />    
</a>
```

And I would like to write, together with some of you, a piece of Javascript/jQuery script that elminates writing some of the lines of the above piece of code.

Let me explain: The

```
- full image (href),
- blackwhite version (data-flare-bw=""),
- lightbox thumb (data-flare-thumb="")
- and the page thumb (<img src=""/>)
```

all have one thing in common: The filename is identical, only the path differs from eachother. So I would like to write/have a script that, based upon a `var` it automatically writes those lines of code. Not only the SRC, but also the attribute itself, so the `href=""`, `data-flare-bw=""`, `data-flare-thumb=""` and the `<image src=""/>`

As I'm not a Jquery master, i'll try to write down the code that, I'd think somewhat give you guys an idea of what should come:

```
$function(InsertAttributesAutomaticcly() {
    var filenames = $('#container a').attr('data-flare-title', this')

    $('#container a').each(function() {
        $(this).append('href', 'images/portfolio/full/' + 'filenames' + '.jpg');
        $(this).append('data-flare-bw', 'images/portfolio/blackwhite/' + 'filenames' + '.jpg');
        $(this).append('data-flare-thumb', 'images/portfolio/thumb/' + 'filenames' + '.jpg');
        $(this).html('<img src=" 'images/portfolio/thumb/' + 'filenames' + '.jpg'">');
    });
});
```

Let me explain the code:
It searches within `#container` for `a` and then appends the `href`, `data-flare-thumb`, `data-flare-bw` tag to it, with the src/url/href image location, which would be  + var (identical to `data-flare-title=""`) + .jpg.
After inserting those three attributes, it inserts a `<img>` within the `a` tag, with an src of `<path> + var (as before) + '.jpg'`

I'm pretty sure this isn't that hard to write, but I'm not that skilled to create a working piece of script, sadly.

Thanks guys!

Bonus task: Those who succesfully write a piece of code above, including a script that tracks the size of the  thumb (width + height) and writes that, next to the , will get a beer from me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted that you have such links for example:

```
<div id="container">
  <a href="#" data-flare-title="1.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#" data-flare-title="2.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#" data-flare-title="3.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

This would be a viable approach:

```
$(function(){

  $('#container a').each(function(){

    var $link = $(this),
        title = $link.data('flare-title');

    $link.attr('href', 'images/portfolio/full/' + title);
    $link.attr('data-flare-bw', 'images/portfolio/blackwhite/' + title);
    $link.attr('data-flare-thumb', 'images/portfolio/thumbs/' + title);

    $link.append($('<img>', {
      src     : 'images/portfolio/thumbs/' + title,
      width   : '375px',
      height  : '250px'
    }));

  });

});
```

Edit: [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eDb43/).

Comment: Wow, thanks mate! Haven't tested yet, but I think I've not been that clear on the <img> part, as the height is the same at all times (250px), yet the width of each <img> thumb is different. For a different plugin, width (and height) of all <img> must be defined, inline. 

Therefor. If it's possible to track the width of the <img file> itself and write that inline, that be great. -- Gonna test the code, in advance. Thanks!

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer either you know it before and embed it into a `data-*` attribute, either you [figure out yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106828/javascript-get-image-height).

Comment: Hm. Both are suitable solutions! Thanks mate, enormously! As written, unless free, pass me down a paypal mail and I'll buy you a beer! =)

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer thank you for being so kind, 5 min of my time are not worth a beer for sure! Feel free to do in case you drop by Berlin : ))

Comment: 5 mins, you're a master! :) - Perhaps next summer, since there are plans to go to Berlin, in fact. Hehe thanks mate!