# Firefox gives wrong values for image width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

From a html5 drag'n drop plugin, i'm getting a data uri of dropped images (or from a file input..).Then i'm setting it as an image src :

```
$("#preview").attr("src",image);
```

Now, i need to make some actions depending on the image dimensions. I tried this by two ways :

1) -  By getting the image height and width from the uri data directly (i got this piece of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106828/javascript-get-image-height)

```
     var curHeight;
     var curWidth;

     function getImgSize(imgSrc)
     {
      var newImg = new Image();
      newImg.src = imgSrc;
      curHeight = newImg.height;
      curWidth = newImg.width;
     }

     getImgSize(The_data_uri);
```

2) by testing on the created image on the html :(here i created two booleans)

```
var lt = function(v1, v2){
    return v1 < v2;
}

var gt400 = (lt(400,parseInt($("#preview").css('width').replace('px', ''))) && lt(400,parseInt($("#preview").css('height').replace('px', ''))) && !window['cropIsOn'] );

var eq400 = (parseInt($("#preview").css('width').replace('px', ''))==400 && parseInt($("#preview").css('height').replace('px', ''))==400) && !window['cropIsOn'] ;
```

On chrome i always got the correct dimensions and therefore tests on dimentions are corrects. However, on firefox it's not correct (i got wrong width and height values). by the way, i'm not trying with different image format for each time(i'm only using jpg images).

i wish to understand why firfox isn't stable about reading height and width.Cheers!

**-EDIT-**

the image which i'm trying to get its dimensions is inside a hidden div

```
<div id="prview_img_wrap" style="position:absolute;top:465px; left:200px;z-index:8; width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;margin-left:5px; border:2px dashed white; visibility:hidden;">
    <img src="" id="preview" />
</div>
```

Comment: I would expect that function to look more like `function getImgSize (imgSrc) {
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.onload = function () {
        curHeight = newImg.height;
        curWidth = newImg.width;
    }
    newImg.src = imgSrc;
}`

Comment: The_data_uri is supposed to be read directly, i don't understand when the onload event you've added will occur...i'll try it anyway thanks

Comment: i got undefined as values.., i told you, values by that function are read direcly, no load event.

Comment: If you don't have an onload event you risk measuring the image before it has been downloaded, which is why you get wrong answers.

Comment: is writting too long javascript files makes browsers having problems ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The height and width of the image are only available after the image is loaded. so this is the correct way:

```
var curHeight;
var curWidth;

function getImgSize(imgSrc){
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.onload = function () {
        curHeight = this.height;
        curWidth = this.width;
    };
    newImg.src = imgSrc;
}
```

Comment: Ibu is right, you have to download the image before you know it's width and height from browser side.

Comment: You'll want to hook up the onload event before you set the src attribute. You're in danger of firing the event before you assign the onload event and may miss it entirely.