# how to return image size with an onclick event from a href

Tags: javascript, html

I want to return image width and height from this a href.

```
<a id="CloudThumb_id_1" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage:   'http://www.example.com/598441_l2.jpg'" onclick="return theFunction();" href="http://www.example.com/598441_l2.jpg">
```

I am testing the theFunction with an alert and its working fine but I am not too sure how to return the height and width?

```
function theFunction () {
        alert('This is a test' );
```

Comment: is it that what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106828/javascript-get-image-height

Comment: Return the size of 598441_l2.jpg in the theFunction()

Comment: oh, you just want to copy the size of the image to the console. The way you worded it sounded like you wished to change the size to a previous value

Answer (score 1):

Well for me this is a sample of what i have done, nothing too fancy with this code, just change the src of the image below and the function will automatically tell you the width and height of your image. i dont know why you have your function returning a value but for me its totally un-necessary. Also, your href link doesn't work

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function theFunction()
    {
        var width1; var height1;
        width1 = document.getElementById("sampleimage").width;
        height1 = document.getElementById("sampleimage").height;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Width = "+width1 + " Height = " + height1;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="sample.jpg" id="sampleimage">
    <div id="output">Height and Width?</div>
    <button type="button" id="samplebutton" onclick="theFunction()">Check</button>
</body>
```

Hope this helps :)