# Determine height of img before loaded with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, blogger

I am trying to modify a widely available Javascript function for use with a Blogger site. The function's purpose is to create a thumbnail and short blurb for each post on the main page. I am attempting to modify the function so it will determine if the picture is portrait or landscape and resize it accordingly (e.g., landscape should 175px wide, portrait should be 175px high). However, whenever I try to make references to the image's height/width, they come up either 0 or null. I believe the problem is that the images have not yet been loaded or written to the page yet.

How can I modify the code below to resolve this?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    summary_noimg = 550;
    summary_img = 450;
    img_thumb_height = 175;
    img_thumb_width = 175; 
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID,pLink){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var img_w = img[0].clientWidth;
    var img_h = img[0].clientHeight;
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if(img.length>=1) {
      if (img_w > img_h) {
        imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><a href="'+pLink+'"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></a></span>';
      }
      else if (img_w <= img_h) {
        imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><a href="'+pLink+'"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px"/></a></span>';
      }

        summ = summary_img;
    }

    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: An image height/width is not known until at least the first part of the image has been downloaded.  The only two choices for getting the height and width are to wait until the image is done being downloaded (when the `load` event fires) or to make a separate Ajax request to obtain the height/width.  Both are asynchronous operations that happen sometime later so your code would have to be restructured to account for the fact that the image height/width is not known until later.

Comment: why don't you wrap the funciton from windows.onload ={}?

Answer (score 1):

What about the following solution: [Javascript - Get Image height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952185/3839692)

It allows you to pass a link to the image before loading it get its info and than you can do what ever logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to determine an image's dimension before it is loaded. The only thing you can do here is wait for the image to be loaded and run the code then, or send a separate Ajax request before the image gets added to your page.

```
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID,pLink){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var img_w = img[0].clientWidth;
    var img_h = img[0].clientHeight;
    var summ = summary_noimg;

    img.addEventListener('load', function () { 
      if(img.length>=1) {
        if (img_w > img_h) {
          imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><a href="'+pLink+'"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></a></span>';
        }
        else if (img_w <= img_h) {
          imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><a href="'+pLink+'"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px"/></a></span>';
        }

        summ = summary_img;
      }
    }, true);


    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}
```