# How to reset image dimensions in javascript? (MVC)

Tags: javascript, html

I got the below javascript function that when you pass in the parameters, it'll load the picture and size it appropriately.  Sometimes I won't know the height and size so therefore how do I reset the image's height (so the browser sizes the image appropriately) and width or delete the height and width properties so that images without passed in sizes aren't shrunk to 0,0 size?  Want to avoid using JQuery.

```
function LoadPicture(picture,alt,text,height,width)
{
    _img = document.getElementById('img')
    _img.src = '/pic/' + picture + '.jpg';
    _img.alt = alt;
    _img.title = text;
    if (height+'' != '' && height>0)
        _img.height = height;
    else {
        _img.height = null;
    }
    if (width+'' != '' && width > 0)
        _img.width = width;
    else _img.width = null;

}
```

Comment: You mean to get it dynamically by reading it from the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the inline styles, so default styling will "kick in":

```
if (height+'' != '' && height>0)
        _img.height = height;
    else {
        _img.removeAttribute("height");
    }
```

Comment: Another way is to use style property like LGSon proposed. Then you can use  _img.style.height = "" to remove the height

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `height`/`width` property to `auto` on the style attribute should solve that

```
function LoadPicture(picture,alt,text,height,width)
{
    _img = document.getElementById('img')
    _img.src = '/pic/' + picture + '.jpg';
    _img.alt = alt;
    _img.title = text;
    if (height+'' != '' && height>0)
        _img.style.height = height;
    else {
        _img.style.height = 'auto';
    }
    if (width+'' != '' && width > 0)
        _img.style.width = width;
    else _img.style.width = 'auto';
}
```

Another way is to read `height`/`width` when an image loads

```
var imgHeight;
var imgWidth;

function findHW() {
  imgHeight = this.height;
  imgWidth = this.width;
  return true;
}

function showImage(imgPath) {
  var myImage = new Image();
  myImage.name = imgPath;
  myImage.onload = findHW;
  myImage.src = imgPath;
}
```

Src: [Javascript - Get Image height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106828/javascript-get-image-height)

More reading at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

---

*A side note (comment made by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5433027/thomas))*

The `image.naturalWidth` and `image.naturalHeight` always contain the natural dimensions of the image, independant of styling and scaling.

Comment: @LGSon, take a look at `myImage.naturalWidth` and `myImage.naturalHeight`. They always contain the natural dimensions of the image, independant of styling and scaling.

Comment: @Thomas Updated my answer with that info