# How do I set background-image height using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like my background image to fill the height of the window on which it is being viewed. Obviously I don't know this value since it is variable. I know it is possible to do what I want using jQuery but after searching SO and google for about an hour without finding an answer to my question, I gave up and decided to ask instead.

I have the background image set to cover it's containing `<div>` using css.

How do I achieve my desired outcome?

Comment: It doesn't have to be done with JS.  Read up on the css `vh` property here: [CSS Viewport Units](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/05/simplify-your-stylesheets-with-the-magical-css-viewport-units/)

Comment: You could do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106828/javascript-get-image-height (There wouldn't be any additional overhead if you're already retrieving the image anyway) Though as people have mentioned, you may not need JS at all.

Comment: `background-size: auto 100%;`

Comment: use this   $('.your_div').css({"background-size": "100%" });

Comment: @E.Owen We do not need to do it by jquery if we use the below code it it handle automatically

Comment: I think I might have worded my question wrong. I don't want the image to span the entire height of the webpage, I just want it to fill the screen as a banner or hero. There will be content below the image with different backgrounds. If I set the height in CSS to 100% it only fills it's containing div.

Comment: @E.Owen can you be more descriptive about the problem if possible please share the image link

Comment: @Anurag_Systematix I want the image to fill the height of the initial viewport. The width will be set to auto. I'm developing locally on my machine so don't currently have a link to show you. The image is  a placeholder which I've resized to 2500x2000px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Jquery  background image according to window height
**See the snippet**

```js
  

$(document).ready(function () {
     var winHeight = $(window).height();
     $('.window-height-bg').css('height', winHeight + 'px');
});
```

```css
   

 body{
      margin:0px;
     }
    .window-height-bg {
       width:100%;
       background:red url(http://i67.tinypic.com/2mqj1iq.jpg) no-repeat;
       background-size:100% 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="window-height-bg">
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need. I'm going to test it now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieve it by using max-width attribute in image tag or on div or by setting the image to body tag

```
max-width: 100%;
```

or like this

```
<body background="http://ssmstorage.blob.core.windows.net/thumbnail/thumbnail_6e9579e9-ec17-4fce-a8cb-6421322b5460.jpg">
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this below code will help you

Please check the link for more detail [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ae9sLejs/)

```
<body  background="w3s.png">
<img style=" display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;" src="http://ssmstorage.blob.core.windows.net/thumbnail/thumbnail_6e9579e9-ec17-4fce-a8cb-6421322b5460.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="50%" height="50%">
<h1>dfksdhfsdfklsdfhsdklfhlskfsdlfjklsf</h1>
<img style=" display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;" src="http://ssmstorage.blob.core.windows.net/thumbnail/thumbnail_6e9579e9-ec17-4fce-a8cb-6421322b5460.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="50%" height="50%">
<h1>dfksdhfsdfklsdfhsdklfhlskfsdlfjklsf</h1>
<img style=" display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;" src="http://ssmstorage.blob.core.windows.net/thumbnail/thumbnail_6e9579e9-ec17-4fce-a8cb-6421322b5460.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="50%" height="50%">
</body>
```